# Objective C memory management issue

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I'm having this issue with some objective C code to load the images on a IKImageBrowserView.
I'm following the image browser example from apple, but I still fail at some point and Im guessing its memory management.
Here is some of the code:

```
/* Our datasource object */
@interface myImageObject : NSObject
{
    NSString *_path; 
}
@end
@implementation myImageObject

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_path release];
    [super dealloc];
}

/* our datasource object is just a filepath representation */
- (void)setPath:(NSString *)path
{
    NSLog(@"setting path for %@",path);
    if(_path != path)
    {
     [_path release];
        _path = [path retain];
    }
}
```

---

Now, It seems I'm properly retaining the path value within the object.
now on to the controller code:

```
-(IBAction)loadMosaicImages:(id)sender
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSArray *urls = [openFiles() retain];
NSInteger n;
n = [urls count];

NSURL *url = [urls objectAtIndex:0];
[self parsePathForImages:[url path]];
[urls release];
[pool drain];
}
- (void)updateDatasource
{
    NSLog(@" UDS-> _importedImages length  : %@",[_importedImages count]);
    //-- update our datasource, add recently imported items    
    [_images addObjectsFromArray:_importedImages];

    //-- empty our temporary array
    [_importedImages removeAllObjects];
    NSLog(@" UDS-> _images length  : %@",[_images count]);
    //-- reload the image browser and set needs display
    [_imageBrowser reloadData];
}
-(void)parsePathForImages:(NSString *)path{

    NSLog(@"Directory within thread method is %@",path);
    NSArray *content = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
    myImageObject *p;
    for(int i=0;i<content.count;i++)
    {
       // NSLog(@"%@",(NSString *)[content objectAtIndex:i]);
        NSLog(@"Complete : %@",[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString *)[content objectAtIndex:i]]);
        /* add a path to our temporary array */
        p = [[myImageObject alloc] init];
        [p setPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[content objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [_importedImages addObject:p];
        [p release];
    }
    [self updateDatasource];
}
```

and that's all the relevant code. _images and _importedImages are NSMutableArrays alloced and inited in the awake from nib method, and openFiles() is a static method that opens an NSOpenpanel and returns an NSArray of the paths.

the debug output for this does this:

```
Directory within thread method is /Users/cromestant/Code/images/
Complete : /Users/cromestant/Code/images/1.jpg
setting path for /Users/cromestant/Code/images/1.jpg
Complete : /Users/cromestant/Code/images/2.jpg
setting path for /Users/cromestant/Code/images/2.jpg
Complete : /Users/cromestant/Code/images/3.jpg
setting path for /Users/cromestant/Code/images/3.jpg
```

.
.
.
 then stops crashes at the first line of the method updateDataSource, on the NSLog with an 'EXEC_BAD_ACCESS'so where am I going wrong with the memory management?
I seem to be creating an autoreleasePool so ht I have time to retain somewhere else, I release my objects.. I really don't have a clue where the problem could be.
thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way I omitted required protocol methods in the post because they aren't really pertinent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think your problem might not be memory management.  It might be here:

```
NSLog(@" UDS-> _importedImages length  : %@",[_importedImages count]);
```

It should be

```
NSLog(@" UDS-> _importedImages length  : %d",[_importedImages count]);
```

because the `count` method returns an integer, not an object.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I feel stupid for this. That is what I get for copy pasting my NSLogs.... changed for %lu and all is ok.

Comment: so basically memory management seems to be ok, I will run through the analyzer later to see, thanks

Comment: No worries, that has happened to me plenty of times, so now I have eyes for it. :)